# What are the under-documented differences between iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X?

Tags: iphone

Besides the differences called out by Apple's comparison site such as price, display type and size, telephone camera, TrueDepth Camera, and Animoji, what are the differences between iPhone 8 and iPhone X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- iPhone X has a [120 Hz touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH108-SW5)  sample rate.
- iPhone X has a [10 channel true tone sensor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvVKnC6gGtg&feature=youtu.be&t=5m40s) and the iPhone 8 has a 4 channel sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Versus does an excellent job with the specs.

https://versus.com/en/apple-iphone-x-vs-apple-iphone-8-vs-apple-iphone-8-plus